# PyQt - how to get top level parent from the given widget?

Tags: qt, pyqt

How can given widget access it's oldest parent, which is top level widget.

I need to `.showMinimized()` it.

Now I am using

```
self.parent().parent().parent().showMinimized()
```

But it seem not to be the best way for this.
If it it moved, I need to change number of parent manually.

Is there a way to access top level widget?

Comment: unrelated: to get to the application object: `QApplication.instance()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're just trying to get to the window widget, there's [QWidget.window()](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#window).

```
self.window().showMinimized()
```

Comment: Yes, thats it. And I also just found pythonic way - `[o.showMinimized() for o in QApplication.topLevelWidgets()]`.